# C plus plus wont loop

Tags: c++

Why wont the code ask the user again when I try running it if the answer is not y or n?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char answer;
    cout << "Do you like cheese?" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if ( answer != 'y' && answer != 'n' ) {
        cout << endl << "Wrong answer, Try again: ";
        cin >> answer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I understand it's not a loop but my other code seems to work fine. If the scored is less than 0, it will keep asking for a number. Why wont this code work then?

```
cout << "Enter the number of goals that were scored: ";
cin >> scored;

if ( scored < 0 ) {
    cout << "Error: the number of goals must be greater than 0. Try again: ";
    cin >> scored;
}
```

Comment: It won't loop without some sort of loop. `for`, `while`, or `do-while` are all loops, while `if` is a branch.

Comment: Where is the loop you are talking about ? There is a `if` statement and nothing else .

Comment: Change the `if` to `while`. And, yes, I do like cheese.

Comment: Read the book about loops do...While is the one you want

Comment: How come this keeps asking the user for scored if its not 0 but my code doesnt?
cout << "Enter the number of goals that were scored: ";
    cin >> scored;
    
    if ( scored < 0 ) {
        cout << "Error: the number of goals must be greater than 0. Try again: ";
        cin >> scored;
    }

Comment: @AkshayPatel: It doesn't keep asking. It asks twice at most.

Comment: Also, don't forget to put `input.clear(); input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` when you have failed input and want to loop again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char answer;
    cout<<"do you like cheese?"<<endl;
    cin>>answer;
    while((answer!='y'&&answer!='n')){
        cout<<"do you like cheese?"<<endl;
        cin>>answer;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Fix your indentation. 2) Code-only answers are frowned upon here - explain what you are doing. 3) `while 1` is unnecessary. Just change the `if` to a `while`.

Comment: 1) resolved, mostly. 2) still outstanding 3) resolved

Answer (score 0):

Change `if` in your `if` statement and replace it with `while`.

```
while ( answer != 'y' && answer != 'n' ) {
    cout << endl << "Wrong answer, Try again: ";
    cin >> answer;
}
```

Then put the rest of your code below:

`//Do what you want with 'answer' here...`